# python: two "fluid" variables reliant on eachother

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my current script:

```
topfactorial = str(facorialmath2)
start = "%s! = "%(factnum)
if len(start) + len(topfactorial) > 2000:
    end = " and %s more digits"%(2000-msglen)
    msglen = 2000 - len(end) - len(start)
    topfacotial = topfactorial[:msglen]
    msg = start+topfacotial+end.format(message)
else:
    msg = start+topfactorial.format(message)
await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

I was writing a block to cut the length of a message short, (due to discord's message length limitation) so I wrote a starting string,(which is fluid, as it returns their input as part of the string), a middle string,(which is the factorial of their input number, so fluid), and an ending string(which tells how many characters had to be cut off to fit within the message limit, so also fluid). My problem is that when calculating the amount of characters to cut off of the middle string, the length of the ending string is required to use to find the total length of all three strings, and cut that many characters off the middle string. However, this amount of characters to be cut off is used in the third string, and thus the two variables rely on each other. This doesn't work, as one of the variables needs to be defined first, but can't because the other isn't. Is there any way to fix this? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not the cleanest way, but put it into a loop till it is the right size. I made small changes for the sake of testing. You need to define everything before you try to define a message length and create a taken variable to count how many are taken. If the message is within length, it will automatically stay 0. The loop will look to keep taking from topfactorial until the message length matches the max length. It also accounts for taken going into double digits, and will remove the correct amount.

```
topfactorial = str(facorialmath2)
start = "%s! = "%(factnum)
taken = 0
end = " and %s more digits"%(taken)
message = start+topfactorial
maxlen = 2000
msglen = len(message)
if msglen > maxlen:
    while msglen > maxlen:
        taken += 1
        truncfactorial = topfactorial[:len(topfactorial)-taken]
        start = "%s! = "%(factnum)
        end = " and %s more digits"%(taken)
        message = start+truncfactorial+end
        msglen = len(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, message)
else:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: there is definitely a smarter way to do this.

```
def truncate(s, limit=2000):
    if len(s) <= limit:
        return s
    addition = ' + {} characters'
    start = limit - len(addition)
    display = s[:start]
    remainder = len(s[start:])
    for i in range(start, 0, -1):
        candidate = display + addition.format(remainder)
        if len(candidate) <= limit:
            return candidate
        display = display[:-1]
        remainder += 1
    raise ValueError('String too big to fit in message')
```